# nested query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, odm, database

How can I query for all tags in following document in mongoDB 2 or 3:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dc45017137a4e70b8b4569"),
    "campainName" : "",
    "themeName" : "theme1",
    "emailListName" : "eiEmails",
    "emailSubject" : "",
    "emailFrom" : "",
    "allNews" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "1",
            "tag" : ['aa','bb','cc'],
            "link" : "",
            "image" : ""
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dc45017137a4e70b8b4570"),
    "campainName" : "",
    "themeName" : "theme2",
    "emailListName" : "afaeiEmails",
    "emailSubject" : "",
    "emailFrom" : "",
    "allNews" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "1",
            "tag" : ['da','db','dc'],
            "link" : "",
            "image" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I need something like this in result:

```
{['aa','bb','cc'], ['da','db','dc']}
```

I need style of query in doctrine odm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

`db.collection.find({}, {"allNews.tag" : 1, _id : 0})`

Comment: it will get you this:

`{
  "allNews": [
    {
      "tag": [
        "aa",
        "bb",
        "cc"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "allNews": [
    {
      "tag": [
        "da",
        "db",
        "dc"
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

Which is probably as close as you'll get without using an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: the answer is correct for this document http://paste.ubuntu.com/12192513/ not for question's document. allNews is a list.